# Java.net.UnknownHostException using httpGet on Android

Tags: android, http-get

I am attempting to use a yahoo finance api that returns a stock quote as a cvs file in Android.  I've reduced the code down to:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=msft&f=sl1p2");
```

I'm getting the following error "java.net.UnknownHostException: download.finance.yahoo.com"

The link works so I'm not sure why I'm getting the exception.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're running this in the emulator, try restarting it. I get this problem very often. Also, if you're using a Mac, you might need to configure the interfaces.

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm using a phone and not an emulator.

Comment: For what it's worth after hours of looking at it, I had my permissions in the wrong place in the manifest.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, by entering the following in AndroidManifest.xml solved it:

> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Answer (score 0):

Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file. like below

```
<manifest xlmns:android...> ...
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >...
    </application>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```